# Using data from API to populate Quasar Tree - trouble sending handler function

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm using Quasar to create a tree:

```
<q-tree v-if="tree"
  :nodes="tree"
  node-key="label"
  default-expand-all
/>
```

If I manually enter the node data and use the handler node property to apply a click function to my nodes, it works great:

```
data () {
    return {
      tree: [ { id: 7, label: 'Master Stateroom', icon: 'crop_3_2', children: [ { id: 4, label: 'Center Bilge Compartment', icon: 'crop_3_2', handler: (node) => this.goCompartment(node) } ], handler: (node) => this.goRoom(node) } ]
    }
  },
```

and my basic, testing methods:

```
methods: {
  goRoom (room) {
    alert(room.id)
  },
  goCompartment (compartment) {
    alert(compartment.label)
  }
}
```

All is good, however, I want to load in my nodes from a database and I'm having trouble getting the handler function to work - it's just a string.

An excerpt from my API:

```
return [ 'id' => $this->id, 'label' => $this->name, 'icon' => 'crop_3_2', 'children' => $children, 'handler' => '(node) => this.goRoom(node)' ];
```

I know I don't want just a string there, it needs to be evaluated as a function. If I review the data in Vue Devtools, I see the handler passed from my API is just a string and the hardcoded, local version, shows up as a function.

Anyone have any tips for passing that correctly from the API to the vue component?